# Alert within useEffect gets thrown before rerender of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem with the code below is: Why is HP displayed as "1" when the alert is thrown and only set to "0" after I confirm the alert? Shouldn't the component be rerendered before the alert is thrown and therefore already been displayed as 0?

At least this is what I conclude from my understanding of useEffect which reads like this:

> useEffect is a hook provided by React that allows you to run side effects in your functional components. It is run after every render cycle of the component.
>
> By default, useEffect runs after the initial render and every update.
> However, you can control when it runs by passing an array of
> dependencies as the second argument. This array contains values that
> the effect depends on, and the effect will only be run when any of
> these values change.

screenshot for better understanding:
[image]

code sandbox link for the code https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-scooby-4t2x0s

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [hp, setHp] = useState(3);

  useEffect(() => {
    
    if (hp === 0) {
      alert("You won!");
    }
  }, [hp]);

  function handleClick() {
    setHp((prev) => {
      return prev - 1;
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {<h1>HP: {hp}</h1>}
      <button style={{ fontSize: "24px" }} onClick={handleClick}>
        Reduce HP by 1
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I did some google/youtube research but couldn't find an explanation.

Comment: useEffect runs on every render of the dependency array, including the first one. could `pokemonNPC.attributes.base.HP` equal to 0 at the first render?

Comment: @Marc there's 3 "*works fine*", as a reader I'm looking to find the "*issue*" and you end up talking about what works.., if we can't understand how your App works it means we won't be able to fix your issue either. Info we need is the *issue* and *data* samples if any is used. Now onto your issue: your understanding of `useEffect` is wrong; because when the component initially renders the `useEffect` is ran, the dependencies are there so that whenever they change the `useEffect` would be re-ran. If `hpPokemonNPC=0` should *not* alert "You won!" then modify the condition into `hpPokemonNPC!==0`

Comment: Hey @Itamar,
thank you for your quick answer! No, it is not 0 at the beginning.
I also edited the post/code to make it clearer and on point.

Comment: Hey @Aleksandar,
thank you for your quick response and the feedback. I edited the post/code to make it clearer and more on point and also added a code sandbox link. The alert should be issued when HP is 0. What I am wondering is why is 0 not already been displayed in the component when the alert is displayed.

Comment: short anwser: alert block main thread(GUI thread). it can be time-out triggered before close . use `console.log`

Comment: Hey @MajidTaheri,
okay and is there a way to modify the code so that it shows the desired behavior?
What do you mean by use console.log?

Comment: @Marc there's actually no issue just the way `alert` blocks the background visual updates, the actuality of your code is indeed running `alert` when `hp===0`, and as comment above suggest you pass it a `setTimeout` like this: [https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-browser-4ou7lb?file=/src/App.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-browser-4ou7lb?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Great, it's working now. Thank you! To clarify, the alert was causing the main thread to block, preventing the actual DOM from updating. The solution is to enclose it in a setInterval function, even with a delay of 0, which pushes it onto the stack to a point behind the actual DOM update. Can one summarise it like this?

Comment: I tried the method in the actual application. The success of this method depends on the timeout interval set, so the position within the stack is not affected. Is there a way to make React execute an action after updating the actual DOM? (useEffect seems to refer to the virtual DOM, which is usually fine but not sufficient in this specific case.)

Comment: @Marc yes, however I'm a bit confused if it's a different question since [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) and [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) are different methods, they do different things so you can't use *interval* and *timeout* interchangeably. Yes the `setTimeout`'s callback (*if hp===0 then alert*) is added onto the callback queue which waits until all synchronous functions calculations are finished, so in this case the `setHp` is executed, then the `alert` is called from the callback queue.

Comment: @Aleksandar Sorry for the confusion - my mistake: I should have called it (the second input parameter of the setTimeout function) delay instead of interval.
The thing is: I adapted the code which you suggested and which runs perfectly fine in the stripped-down example in code sandbox example to my actual application.
However, what I observe there:
- if the delay is between 0-3: the alert gets issued before the correct HP value is delayed
- if the delay is 4 or higher it works as you suggested

Comment: From my observations, it seems that the updating of the actual DOM and the execution of setTimeout are asynchronous processes and that the success of the solution with the setTimeout is dependent on the CPU speed and the specified delay. Probably a delay of let's say 100 will suffice in 99.99% of the cases, but I am curious if there is a more sophisticated solution than relying on a timeout with a lengthy delay to ensure proper execution.

Answer (score 1):

To combine comments into an answer,
[`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) *waits until the user dismisses the dialog*; with that in mind you may want to implement a modal yourself or use [react-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal) library or find ideas on YouTube.

If you still want to use `alert` method, the workaround will be to use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) conditionally inside the `useEffect` like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (hp === 0) {
    // pass it a timeout
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert("You won!");
    }, 0);
  }
}, [hp]);
```

CodeSandbox: [https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-browser-4ou7lb](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-browser-4ou7lb?file=/src/App.js)

However, this is redundant to call `useEffect` every time `hp` updates is unnecesary.

To boost your app performance, taking in consideration that `handleClick` is pure function that only reduces `hp` by `-1` you can use it to your advantage to have the alert in there.

(*And as a side-note in your real app I'd personally suggest you rename it to `reduceHPbyOne` or something more descriptive.*)

Code will be like this:

```
function handleClick() {
  if (hp === 1) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert("You won!");
    }, 0);
  }
  setHp((prev) => {
    return prev - 1;
  });
}
```

CodeSandbox link: [https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-roentgen-x4cdj8](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-roentgen-x4cdj8?file=/src/App.js)

The code is pretty simple with a little modification: when `hp===1` then `alert('You won!')` because, again, `handleClick` decreases `hp` by `-1`.

You are certain `setHp` will re-render with `hp-1` update, and in a case scenario where `hp===1` condition is `true`, what happens is: React updates `hp` to `0` and `alert` is run afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of `useEffect` is in fact correct!

However `alert` is a bit special as it basically blocks any render in the browser until it has been closed.

You can simply wrap your alert in a setTimeout, even with no delay, as it allows the render cycle to re-render before alert blocks the render;

```
setTimeout(() => { alert("You won!") }, 0);
```

But even better would probably be not to use an `alert`, and instead make some nice "in-game" graphics? ;-)